# How to upload large file make into chunk files (Slice Size:2GB) using Javascript or Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to upload large file size make into chunk files (Slice Size:2GB) using Javascript or Angular2 ?

[image: Issue Description]

Comment: Try resumable js

Comment: Hi Rajeev Radhakrishnan, Can you give me some sample example how to use resumable js, Because I am using angular6 application.

Comment: public sliceSize = 262144000;

Comment: const blob = this.slice(this.file, this.start, end);
      const blobAsFile = new File([blob], this.file.name, { type: this.file.type, lastModified: this.file.lastModified });
      console.log(blobAsFile);
      this.uploadChunk(blobAsFile, this.start, end);

Comment: public uploadChunk(file, start, end) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('start', start);
    formData.append('end', end);
    formData.append('file', file);

    // Make Service Call on success below statement
    const URL = any
    this.httpClientService.putFile(URL, formData).subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.start += this.sliceSize;
        this.readSlice();
      } else {
        this.start += this.sliceSize;
        this.readSlice();
      }
    });

  }

Comment: Think about what your asking for a second; the answer is quite obvious. You take your byte array, read x number of bytes into a byte array and send that along the wire. At the other end, you stitch them back together. You can do it asynchronous and just pass along each chunk's start and end. Just make sure you're math is right on the start and end indexes and you'll be fine.

Comment: Dear Richard, Can you plz give me any example how to upload 5GB file using slice of 2GB help of asynchronous call in angular6???

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the chunk size. The maximum chuck/file size handled by browsers is 2GB. So reducing the chuck size to less than that should fix the Network_Reset issue.